What does a prometheus gauge record if I call the Set() function multiple times before a scrape?
I think that the documentation is not clear about the value(s) that a gauge records when using a Set().
Will the object save all the values or does it keep only the last one until the next scraping happens?
I would hope it is the former (all values saved), especially if the scraping interval is pretty long (like say 1 minute and I do one Set() about once a second, I would imagine I'd get nearly 60 values sent on the next scraping).
Which is correct?
